# Create Database and Tables with NHibernate and FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm looking for any way to create `database` and `tables` with NHibernate and FluentNHibernate.

How could I do this ?

trying.

```
private static ISessionFactory createConnection()
{
    if (session != null)
        return session;

    //database configs
    FluentConfiguration _config = Fluently.Configure().Database(
        MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
            x => x.Server(HOST).
            Username(USER).
            Password(PASSWORD).
            Database(DB)
        ))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PerfilMap>())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ModuloMap>())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PermissaoMap>())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UsuarioMap>())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CategoriaMap>())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SubcategoriaMap>    ())
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true));

    session = _config.BuildSessionFactory();
    return session;
}
```

Comment: You want to create the database with tables in the DBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither NHibernate nor FNH create the database itself. You have to provide either code or a precreated database yourself. But it can create the tables for you. The class doing this is call `SchemaExport`. In Fluent, it looks like this:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(/* ... */)
   .Mappings(/* ... */)
   .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false))
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Shamelessly copied from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451761/getting-fluent-nhibernate-to-build-database-tables).

Comment: I created a project in Java with Hibernate to create the database first, and after it I used NHibernate to create tables, it work for me. I would use only Nhibernate but I can't find any solution to it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

One full implementation could be:

For one entity class like *Genre* there will be a mapping class like *GenreMap*. And a general nhibernate helper class to get a session to db(SessionFactory) class for mapping all entities to database:

```
public class Genre
{
    public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class GenreMap : ClassMap<Genre>
{
    public GenreMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.GenreId).Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Table("Genres");
    }
}
```

and finally in SessionFactory class:

```
public static class SessionFactory
{
    private static ISessionFactory _factory;

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return _factory.OpenSession();
    }

    public static void Init(string connectionString)
    {
        _factory = BuildSessionFactory(connectionString);
    }

    private static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL81
                .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString))
                .ShowSql())

            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<GenreMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

And the usage will be like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        var persons = session.Query<Genre>().ToList();

        return View(persons);
    }
}
```

And in Startup class:

```
SessionFactory.Init(connectionString);
```

Comment: Hi this is my last answer sorry for the editing many times , you can try it